# Bluetooth reconnect

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I've got a question concerning blueooth connections. I set-up a bluetooth connection to my device (Arduino Nano with bluetooth shield) and for whatever reason that connection might fail. That's ok, it's bluetooth and that happens for instance when the device is out of range. But when possible, I want the connection to reestablish. It's this part I'm having issues with; the code to connect just won't work any longer. What does seem to work is rebooting the device (just rebooting the app is not enough). After having rebooted the Pi, connections are alive and kicking again.

So there seems to be something stuck that's fixed after a reboot, but I'd like to know how to fix this without needing to reboot. Anyone?

**Update** some more background info. I'm using the Firmata library to connect with and control the Arduino's. I do have control over both sides although I'm less comfortable with changing the firmata code.

Comment: "**the code to connect just won't work any longer**" what's the error information? Have you tried unpair and pair again?

Comment: I have not tried that since this needs to work without human interaction. I'm not sure whether it's actually possible to pair / unpair from code, but on the other hand that would be kind of strange should it be necessary, right?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I assume here that you have control on any of your devices. Control meaning you can modify the code so that device can try to reconnect.

**Issue**

Now, in your case, when the device goes out of range, connection gets disconnected but when they come in range none of your device inherently try to reconnect to other device. Unless you have code written which try to keep reconnecting to its last connected device, none of the device will try to connect even if they are in range. When you are restarting your device, your aurdino device might be trying to reconnect to all/last connected device due to which reconnection takes place.

**Solution**

To solve your issue, you can add a piece of code preferably at aurdino side to try to keep reconnecting to the last connected device at regular interval of say 5 seconds.

**Limitation**

However, this is more like polling where you don't exactly know if the device is actually in range. In bluetooth, this is not possible to know if a device has come in range until we do scan for the device. Only issue which you have to face with this solution is it will need more power as it will try to reconnect through bluetooth at regular interval even if device is not present.

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: I have control over the devices, yes. I'm using firmata to connect and control the Arduinos remotely. I do not think that those devices are reconnecting, there's no retry / reconnect logic in Firmata as far as I know.

Comment: Firmata is a communication protocol between the host and arduino, there's of course no retry/reconnect logic in Firmata and you shouldn't develop such. As akasonlyaks says, write the re-connection logic codes that runs at a regular interval at Arduino side.

Comment: I understand, but at Arduino side the only thing that is loaded is the firmata code. The bluetooth connection is as simple as wiring in the TX/RX and starting Serial, that's pretty much it. So I'm not sure on how I should incorporate retry logic there.